# Why does other-window-for-scrolling ignores variable other-window-scroll-buffer?

Tags: buffers, window, scrolling

According to the documentation of `other-window-for-scrolling` we should be able to specify the "other window" by setting the variable `other-window-scroll-buffer`:

> other-window-for-scrolling is a built-in function in ‘src/window.c’.
>
> (other-window-for-scrolling)
>
> Return the other window for "other window scroll" commands. If in the
> minibuffer, ‘minibuffer-scroll-window’ if non-nil specifies the
> window. Otherwise, if ‘other-window-scroll-buffer’ is non-nil, a
> window showing that buffer is used, popping the buffer up if
> necessary. Finally, look for a neighboring window on the selected
> frame, followed by all visible frames on the current terminal.

However, in reality this seems to be ignored:

```
(setq other-window-scroll-buffer "*R*")

(other-window-for-scrolling) --> #<window 558 on header.html>
```

Is this a bug or feature that was removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc for `other-window-scroll-buffer` says:

> *If this is a live buffer*, C-M-v should scroll its window.

(emphasis added). IOW, the value *must* be a buffer, not the name of a buffer. So try:

```
(setq other-window-scroll-buffer (get-buffer "*R*"))
```

`get-buffer` is a function that returns a buffer, given its name (a string). If no such buffer exists, it returns `nil`. See its doc string with `C-h f get-buffer`.

Comment: I tried this and did not work for me. Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it did: do you have a live buffer called `*R*`? In my case, I set my shell buffer to be the scrolling buffer and `other-window-for-scrolling` returns it (and makes it visible in a window if it is not visible to begin with) and `C-M-v` scrolls it (and also makes it visible if necessary).

Comment: yes it works. I had the wrong name it is suppose to be:other-window-scroll-buffer not other-window-scrolling-buffer.
Thanks

Comment: That's my fault: I screwed up the spelling of the variable and instead of cutting and pasting the code, I retyped it getting it wrong in the process. Apologies and thanks. I fixed up the answer.